# How to make this partial derivative where both variables are Ln()?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this function:
$$\ Ln (y)  = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1D + \gamma_2ln(X)+\gamma_3M+\gamma_4Dln(X)+\gamma_5DM+V $$

I would like to know how to apply this partial derivative:
$$ \frac{∂ln(Y)}{∂ln(X)}$$

I know how to it if Y and X were not ln(). But in this case, I'm lost. Any explanation would be great.

Comment: Please write explicitly the function. Images are a pain to work with.

Comment: Please see the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @projectilemotion  Done :V